# Select all shift Subslips where this Employee isn't already working a shift

Tags: php, mysql, select

I currently have a select statement that will retrieve all the subslips from the subslip table that the employee can take if they have the certification for the subslip. I Just need to make the select statement return only subslips that do not conflict with any of the shifts the employee currently has.

A subslip is an contract of exchange of shifts between two employees. I am trying to make my web app display all subslips that the employee can take. If they click take shift on the subslip, the web app takes the shift from the old employee and gives it to the new one.

The select statement I currently have is...

```
SELECT S.CreatorID, S.ShiftID, S.subslipID, S.ShiftDate, S.startTime, S.endTime, S.Position, S.Reason, S.CreatedDateAndTime, E.Firstname, E.Lastname, E.Instructor, E.Lifeguard, E.Headguard, E.Supervisor 
FROM `SubSlips` S 
JOIN `Employees` E ON S.CreatorID = E.employeeID 
WHERE `TakenTrueorFalse` = '0' 
AND ShiftDate > '".$todaysDate."'
AND ( Position = 1 OR Position = 2 OR Position = 3 OR Position = 4 OR Position = 10);
```

This displays all subslips the employee can take based on wheather it taken or not, if the subslip's date is ahead of today's date, and if the subslips is one of the positions that the employee has certifications for.

I believe the select statement needs a "NOT IN (SELECT shifts that are at the same time"  attached to the end of the statement.

```
NOT IN(
    SELECT ShiftID FROM Shifts 
    WHERE `CurrentOwnerEmployeeID` = '".$EmployeeID."'
       AND `date` = S.ShiftDate
        AND  `startTime` Between S.startTime AND S.endTime
    OR `date` = S.ShiftDate 
        AND `endTime` Between S.startTime AND S.endTime
    OR `date` = '".$date."' 
        AND S.startTime Between `startTime`  AND `endTime`)
```

My Employee table looks like this...
[image: Employee Table]

My shift table looks like this...
[image: ShiftTable]

This is the SubSlip Table...
[image]

So how can I make my Select Statement return the subslips that the currently logged in employee doesnt already have a shift at that time?

Edit
This is my select statement with the not in logic added.

```
 SELECT S.CreatorID, S.ShiftID, S.subslipID, S.ShiftDate, S.startTime, 
S.endTime, S.Position, S.Reason, S.CreatedDateAndTime, E.Firstname, 
E.Lastname, E.Instructor, E.Lifeguard, E.Headguard, E.Supervisor FROM 
`SubSlips` S JOIN `Employees` E ON S.CreatorID = E.employeeID WHERE 
`TakenTrueorFalse` = '0' AND ShiftDate > '2017-12-31' 
AND ( Position = 1 OR Position = 2 OR Position = 3 OR Position = 4 OR 
Position = 10) AND 
NOT IN(    SELECT ShiftID FROM Shifts 
WHERE `CurrentOwnerEmployeeID` = '8' AND
`date` = S.ShiftDate AND 
`startTime` Between S.startTime AND S.endTime
OR `date` = S.ShiftDate AND `endTime` Between S.startTime AND S.endTime 
OR `date` = S.ShiftDate AND S.startTime Between `startTime` AND `endTime`);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, see about In() and (slightly paradoxically) parametrised queries

Comment: Also, seriously consider storing date and time as single entities